GTFS Loop route that is more than one loop
Simplified: I have a route with 6 stops: Stop A, Stop B, Stop C, Stop D, and Stop E.  In the morning the bus begins the trip at the outer timing point Stop A.  After noon, the bus switched and begins the trip at the inner timing point Stop C.   This results in 1 trip where that switch has to be made. Currently the scheduler is scheduling the trip as:

Stop A
Stop B
Stop C
Stop D
Stop E
Stop A
Stop B
Stop C

Which allows the next trip to be: Stop C,E, D, A, B, C.
Am I correct in thinking that the scheduler needs to split that trip into two trips:

Stop A
Stop B
Stop C
Stop D
Stop E
Stop A
and
Stop A
Stop B
Stop C

And is there anything in the spec that references that? I know that there is an "Trip Is Too Long" error that I've seen on this before.
